# How to Cast today data as bigint to Data - 202104171830

Tags: sql-server, query

I have got today's data as Bigint: **202104171830**. How could I cast this Bigint value to today's date ? Please help. MSSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if only date:

```
select convert(date, substring('202104171830',1,8))
```

Comment: Great thank You very much :)

Comment: and how get a hours ?

Comment: @GrzegorzZ, to get time components, you'll need to substring the value as David mentioned. You could additionally use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql) and specify the substring for each component of interest (i.e. year, month, day, hour, and zero for the other values).

Answer (score 1):

1. First use `CAST()` to convert it to a string representing that same value
2. Then construct a new string my using `SUBSTRING()` to pull out the parts and add punctuation as needed, i.e. `SUBSTRING(@TimestampIntAsString, 1, 4)` to pull out the year, so you end up with `'2021-04-17 18:30'`
3. Then the `CAST()` function will recognise that as an ISO8601-ish datetime that it can convert to a proper `DATETIME` value.

Just make `'2021-04-17'` and cast to `DATE` if you don't need the time portion.

IIRC none of the conversion functions in SQL Server will recognise a datetime without punctuation as a valid date representing string, as some systems will, so you can't avoid the tedious mucking about with `SUBSTRING()`.